# How to deploy SWF file?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript, embedded-resource

I have a SWF file I created using Adobe Flex and I cannot seem to properly embed it inside an HTML page.  If I take another SWF file and use it instead, it works all the time.  My SWF file is pretty big (1 MB) while the other one is tiny (25 KB).  However, I can wait 5-10 minutes and the server connection is super fast and it still will never load.

Is there something I need to do to the SWF to have it start up properly?  My SWF almost never runs.

Thoughts?

Comment: Need more information here: How are you embedding the SWF file? Is the SWF file actually loaded or is flash saying "Movie not found" when you right click the flash frame on your page? Does your 1MB SWF file run correctly from your IDE (flex builder)?

Answer (score 2):

I see two posible problems here:

- Browser is not able to download your SWF file

  - You can check it if you add SWF file name directly into browser URL. For example `http://your_domain/page/test.swf`. If you will get "Not Found" error then your file was uploaded incorrectly
- You did something wrong when embeding SWF file into HTML

  - If you have a working file then you can try to overwrite it with new one (leave original file name). Problem can be in sigle symbol in new file name, even letter case should match.
  - Or you can try using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) library for embeding flash into html